# AJAX success event does not get triggered after server change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which was executing perfectly on a previous webserver. However, it's not completing the SUCCESS part of the code now. I'm unsure of the exact differences in servers and don't have access to them at that level.

I'm wondering though whether there's an error in this code anyway, as when I view it in Dreamweaver the colouring stops working part way through. I attached the screenshot, so you can see what I mean. Any ideas what might fix that colouring? Perhaps it's the same thing that is causing the script to fail.
Thanks.

```
function upload(id, pupilID, statementID, firstName, goalText) {
    var ext = $("#" + id).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert('Invalid File Type. Only Standard JPG/JPEG Files Are Allowed. This Is The Standard/Default File Type Of Most Mobile Devices & Digital Cameras.');
        return;
    }

    $("#assess").hide();
    $("#progressWrapper").show();

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('input_file_name', $("#" + id).prop('files')[0]);
    data.append("type", 'savePhoto');
    data.append("pupilID", pupilID);
    data.append("statementID", statementID);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: 'ajax.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        xhr: function (){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                    var percent = 0;
                    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                    var total = event.total;
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    }
                    $('.first.circle').circleProgress({
                        value: (percent / 100),
                        animation: false,
                        fill: {gradient: ['#ff1e41', '#ff5f43']}
                    });
                    $("#percentValue").html(Math.round(100 * (percent / 100)) + '<i>%</i>');
                }, true);
            }
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function (response)
        {
            $("#progressWrapper").hide();
            $("#preTagged2").html('<b>' + firstName + '</b>');
            $("#tagStudents").show();
            $("#taggedPupilWas").val(pupilID);
            $("#taggedStatementWas").val(statementID);
            $("#taggedForenameWas").val(firstName);
            $("#taggedGoalTextWas").val(goalText);
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver syntax highlighting has no way of knowing that something changed on your server. The issues are not related.

Here's how you can debug your problem:

1. Open your website
2. Press F12 to open **Developer tools**
3. Click Network tab
4. Perform the action on your website which will trigger
   `upload()`
5. In **Network tab** you can see all network requests that your website made
6. Find your request and check if the server is returning the correct response

If the server is returning an incorrect response, you can:

- adjust your code so it would process the new responses
- (more likely) contact someone to fix the problem on the server

Comment: thanks for the Developer tools tips... turns out it's a PHP issue in the ajax call... something that was allowed in the old version, isn't in the new! Typical! Unfortunately all I get to see is a 500 error! ;-)

Comment: No problem. :) Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check under votes on the left.

Comment: done so, thanks :-) All sorted now. A pesky undeclared php variable.... XAMPP just seemed to ignore it.... settings in IIS throw up a 500 error page straight away, which was causing the lack of AJAX success :-)